# Need a circuit for switching 200kHz 24V-36V signal

Tags: pwm, switching

I need a suggestion for a N-P ch Mosfet configuration circuit that could switch 200kHz PWM signal at 24V-36V. Input for this circuit is PWM signal is MCU 3.3V pin.

UPDATE:
Load is ultrasonic transducer. Current is less than 10mA.

Comment: Too much voltage for an FOD8343.

Comment: What is your expected load current? Answers would be very different.

Comment: Load is ultrasonic transducer. Current is less than 10mA.

Comment: What about using a power OpAmp?

Comment: Best choise would be as simple and as cheap circuit as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost any small signal bipolar transistors will do. 2N3904/2N3906 have maximum C-E voltage of 40V, so that'll work at 24V with ample margin. For 36V operation, more margin would be nice, so the options are:

- BC547/BC557 - 45V,
- BC637/BC638 - 60V.

No need for a mosfet - in this application, a bipolar transistor will likely perform better, since it doesn't have the heavy gate capacitance.

To get most output out of the transducer for any given voltage, you'll want to drive it using an H bridge, so the transistors would have to be arranged that way. Or just use an integrated H bridge and call it a day.